# Email-Ext plugin does not work for custom groovy templates

Tags: email, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have installed `Email-ext plugin version 2.30.2` in jenkins server (version is 1.520) . I am using custom groovy template to send a html content type in the email notifications.Though i have placed the template under `JENKINS_HOME\email-templates` still I am not getting HTML content in emails.

Under Jenkins -> Configuration , i have properly mentioned the SMTP server details and other fields , for the "Default Content" field I have mentioned `${SCRIPT,template="groovy-ABCD.template"`

Answer (score 0):

Check that the 'Default Content Type' is HTML (text/html) in the master configuration.  If it is set correctly there check the configuration of the specific job to make sure that it is set to 'Default Content Type.'

If the master is set to plain text either change the content type to HTML or change the specific job content type to HTML.